# what type of programming is used for 3g mobiles

Tags: mobile, 3g

which type of programming is used for 3g mobiles

Comment: Which 3g mobile?  My iPhone or your Android?

Comment: What do you mean with programming? You often use different techniques if you write core mobile functions or if you write an app for the end user.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the mobile ; if by 3g mobile you mean smartphones, you would use Objective-c / Cocoa for iPhone, Java for Android phones.

Comment: is there any change in OS from 2G to 3G

Comment: @Sagar: Often you have an abstraction layer so that you don't need to care about what technology the phone is using to connect. The "change" might be that you are able to write apps that uses more bandwidth (streaming video for example).